prevent new line after macros usage for clang-format c++
imagine that we have macros for formatted log construction, for example:
LOG(log_level)("key1", "value1")("key2", "value2")...;

in this case we will have in formatter result:
LOG(log_level)
("key1", "value1")("key2", "value2")...;

i tried formatter config:
currently, i have next clang-formatter config:
BasedOnStyle: Google
IndentWidth: 4
ColumnLimit: 0
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 3
AlignAfterOpenBracket: false
AlignTrailingComments:
  Kind: Never
  OverEmptyLines: 2
InsertBraces : true
ReflowComments: false
PenaltyBreakComment: 0
DerivePointerAlignment: true
PointerAlignment: Left
AccessModifierOffset: -4
IndentCaseLabels: true
InsertNewlineAtEOF: true
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine : false
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine : false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine  : false
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine : false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine : false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: false
BitFieldColonSpacing: After


LOG(log_level)("key1", "value1")("key2", "value2")...;

how i can correct my configuration to avoid line breaking in same cases?

Can you show a more realistic code w/o ... for debugging? Can you show which of the shown 3 codes is your desired code and the failed formatted result.

WhitespaceSensitiveMacros might do the trick https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Thnx for answer in comments:
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros is enough for usage with purpose result
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - LOG

In result i havent problem with specific macroses:
AFL_WARN(COMPONENT_NAME)("event", "skip_inserted_data")("reason", "table_removed")("path_id", GetPathId());

in this example formatter dont make break in line after macros usage directly.
